# java чтение ресурсов Maven из resources

Tags: java, maven, resources

в моем учебном maven проекте есть такой класс, который читает содержимое файла и возвращает лист стрингов:

```
public class FileReader {
public List<String> readFile(String fileName) {
    if (fileName == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("fileName can't be null");
    }
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);        
    if (url == null) {
        throw new ReadFileException("file " + fileName + " was not found or access to the resource is denied");
    }
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(url.toURI()))) {
        return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new ReadFileException("error occurs opening the file " + fileName, e);
    }
}
```

}

этот класс читает кое-какие файлы из папки
myproject\src\main\resources
и потом листы дальше передаются в другие классы.
Все работает нормально, пока запускается в ide.
maven без проблем собирает проект в jar, проходят тесты и тд, но, как только пытаюсь запустить этот jar файл в консоли (java -jar myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT) - летит ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
> at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:171)
> at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:157)
> at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
> at org.project.input.FileReader.readFile(FileReader.java:24)
> at org.project.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:31)

Я понимаю, что проблема где-то здесь :`getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)`

но не могу понять в чем, помогите плиз, если кто знает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что при упаковке в jar, файл, который запакован не существует в файловой системе, как собственно файл. То есть он недоступен ни по одному пути в файловой системе. URL полученый с помощью `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource` указывает внутрь jar, он состоит из двух частей: путь к jar + путь внутри jar.

Таким образом доступ с помощью `Paths` или `File` просто используя этот URL - это непереносимый способ доступаться к ресурсу. Он работает, когда ресурс существует как файл, но не будет работать, когда он упакован в архив jar.

Переносимый способ - это использовать `getResourceAsStream`:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass()
   .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");
```

чтобы получить InputStream для файла ресурса, который находится в корне `resources`. И дальше уже читать содержимое из этого потока.

Реализация `getResourceAsStream` в каждом ClassLoader своя, и таким образом доступ к ресурсам будь-то классы или другие файлы работает и в случае упаковки их в jar - в этом случае используется специфичный для jar ClassLoader.

Comment: спасибо! стало все понятно!

Comment: На самом деле что-то мне тут не ясно. Я посмотрел, под капотом getResourceAsStream использует тот же самый getResource, просто открывает для него поток. Получается, по факту разницы-то никакой.

Comment: Мм, хотя да, это я говорю про дефолтную реализацию в абстрактном ClassLoader, а так-то в разных наследниках она действительно разная. Однако, почему это не указано в документации к методу? не могли бы вы дать ссылку на информацию о том, почему у getResource и getResourceAsStream разное поведение? Особенно, если учитывать то, что в самом ClassLoader поведение этих двух методов по сути не отличается

Comment: Почему вы пишете, что поведение разное? В каком смысле разное? В правильной реализации отличие между ними только в том `getResource` возвращает URL, а `getResourceAsStream` возвращает содержимое. И для вас, как для клиента, проблема в том, что URL может быть разный, т.е. может быть разная схема, может быть http, или файл или ресурс в jar-файле, или вообще кастомный URL. И вашему коду, который использует `getResource` нужно быть готовым к этому и уметь все случаи обрабатывать. `getResourceAsStream` возвращает содержимое независимо от того, где ресурс находится и какая схема в URL используется