# Ошибка при исполнении JAR-файла: файл не найден

Tags: java, файлы, консоль

Я написал небольшую программу, которая генерирует табличку с текстом. Сами таблички реализованы через itextpdf. Для того, чтобы табличка корректно отображала кириллицу, я использую шрифт Helvetica.

Переменной FONT передается расположение шрифта, который находится в папке Resources[image: расположение в проекте]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String FONT = "./src/main/resources/HelveticaRegular.ttf";
```

Но когда я собираю *.jar файл, после попытки запуска в консоли выводится сообщение:

> Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Font file ./src/main/resources/HelveticaRegular.ttf not found.

Если передавать полный путь к файлу, например:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String FONT = "C:\\Users\\megavatt\\Desktop\\HelveticaRegular.ttf";
```

то программа работает корректно.

Проблема в том, что я должен доставлять файл со шрифтом, для того, чтобы приложение работало, но мне неизвестна директория пользователя. Я могу как-то запустить приложение в консоли с тем шрифтом, который находится в папке resources?

Сделал вот так,

```
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/HelveticaRegular.ttf");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

И появилась ошибка:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:76)
    at main.java.Main$1Font.<init>(Main.java:28)
    at main.java.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1402240/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8/1402265#1402265 так же смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1279699/218971

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA не могли бы вы немного подробнее подсказать? Я просто не совсем понимаю как оно работает. Перепробовал уже кучу вариантов разных, в некоторых оно выдает путь типа "jar:file:/C:/Users/megavatt/Desktop/User_Generator.jar!/HelveticaRegular.ttf", это не работает. У меня далее передается все вот так: PdfFont russian = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, "Identity-H", true); и если я передаю потоком, то оно ломается

Comment: Вариант с файлом не годится. По ссылкам, что я дал написано почему - в случае jar файла в файловой системе просто не существует файла со шрифтом, он запакован в архиве (в url видите префикс jar:). Варианты решения для вас: 1. прочитать InputStream и сохранить все в памяти как массив т.е. `byte[]`, и потом использовать `createFont` не с строкой - путем к файлу, а с массивом типа [этой](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.0.7/com/itextpdf/kernel/font/PdfFontFactory.html#createFont-byte:A-java.lang.String-boolean-) 2. сохранить данные из `InputStream` во временный файл и его уже использовать