# Jar не получается считать файл

Tags: java, файлы, intellij-idea, jar

Когда я запуская данный код в IntelliJ все работает когда же я запускаю в виде jar файл
выдает такую ошибку

```
    File file = new File("src/main/java/users/txt.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileReader);
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(s);
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\java\users\txt.txt (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:75)
        at main.main(main.java:10)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [java чтение ресурсов Maven из resources](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1279693/java-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-maven-%d0%b8%d0%b7-resources) да и тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1402240/218971  похожий вопрос

Comment: я уже отвечал на подобные вопросы раз 10... попробуйте поискать - гарантировано получится

Answer (score 0):

Вы указываете относительный путь, начиная с директории запуска .jar.

Вам стоит либо сменить путь с `src/main/java/users/txt.txt` до `txt.txt` и переместить txt.txt в одну директорию с .jar

Либо вы уже сейчас можете, ничего не меняя, переместить файл .jar из директории для создания .jar по умолчанию в директорию, где лежит папка src.

Также, будет считаться более правильным, если вы поместите txt.txt в `src/main/resources`, а после его можно будет считать **так**:

```
InputStream is = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("txt.txt");
```

**UPD:**
Если вы запускаете .jar из командной строки, тогда следует сначала перейти к директории, где лежит директория src с помощью команды:

```
cd ПОЛНЫЙ_ПУТЬ_К_ДИРЕКТОРИИ_С_SRC
```

А потом запускать jar с помощью:

```
java -jar PATH_TO_JAR/name.jar
```